# Triangle border

Tags: html, css

I want to code a news's div border with bottom transparent triangle but left triangle border isn't equal to right, can you explain me why or let me know other way to code it?

My code:

```css
.news {

 position: relative;
 margin: 75px auto;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px #079199 solid;
 padding: 20px;
 
 color: #bcbcbc;
 
 word-wrap: break-word;
 
}

.news:after {
 
 position: absolute;
 content: '';

 border: 25px solid transparent;
 border-top-color: #FFF;
 
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
}

.news:before {
 
 position: absolute;
 content: '';

    border-left: 26px solid transparent;
    border-right: 26px solid transparent;
    border-top: 26px solid;
    border-top-color: #079199;
 
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  TEST
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but where is there a _triangle_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the alignment of the two pseudo elements was wrong, try to use this:

```css
.news {

 position: relative;
 margin: 75px auto;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px #079199 solid;
 padding: 20px;
 
 color: #bcbcbc;
 
 word-wrap: break-word;
 
}

.news:after,
.news:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #ffffff;
  
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.news:before {
   border: 26px solid transparent;
   border-top-color: #079199;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  TEST
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning both `50%` from the left. In order to see the border, you'll have to offset the colored `:before` triangle slightly less left.

We can do this by applying a negative `margin-left`

```css
.news {
  position: relative;
  margin: 75px auto;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px #079199 solid;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #bcbcbc;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.news:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #FFF;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}

.news:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-left: 26px solid transparent;
  border-right: 26px solid transparent;
  border-top: 26px solid;
  border-top-color: #079199;
  margin-left: -1px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="news">
  TEST
</div>
```